# Problem returning Results in JSON from Web App .Net Core 5

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

Good afternoon colleagues, I have the following problem. I am developing a project in ASP.NET Core MVC (.NET 5) And within it I have the call to an API, the APIs return the values ​​in JSON without problems but when I try to read from code it never goes beyond line 39 (`return Json(ppodcastPortada);`). In other words, it never reaches the teturn.

I am making the call from JavaScript, to render it asynchronously on the page. But the controller never returns the set of results, I really don't know why.

My Controller:

```
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public class PodcastController : Controller
    {

        #region "Async call API"

        
        public async Task<JsonResult> GetPodcastLandingPortada()
        {
            
            List<PPodcast> ppodcastPortada = new List<PPodcast>();
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44379/api/Podcast/ObtenerPodcastPortadaPrincipal"))
                {
                    string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    ppodcastPortada = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PPodcast>>(apiResponse);
                }
            }

            return Json(ppodcastPortada);

        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe if you change the signature to IActionResult and return Ok(ppodcastPortada).

Comment: Hi, I managed to solve it effectively by changing the signature, but it didn't go past that line, until I change the result by string. Now if it passes and delivers values. But the problem is that my javascript can't read it, I don't know why it comes out undefined

Comment: Hmm. You will have to debug this and see what it is doing. Difficult to see what is going on could be multiple things. It might be deserializing wrong for instance

Comment: Can you share your api,as `Daniaal` said,maybe the data cannot be deserialized to `List<PPodcast>`.